# S4cmd working only for Amazon S3. Is it possible to configure it for DreamObjects cloud storage the way S3cmd worked?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud-storage, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I just switched from [S3cmd](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd) to [S4cmd](https://github.com/bloomreach/s4cmd). It's working great for EC2 to Amazon S3 data transfer. But when I'm trying [DreamObjects](https://www.dreamhost.com/cloud/storage/) or [CenturyLink Object](https://www.ctl.io/object-storage/) storage in it's place, it shows the below error:

> ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the
>   ListBuckets operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not
>   exist in our records.

I properly configured `.s3cfg` for DreamObjects, I know it because when I type `s3cmd ls` it lists the buckets. But when I type `s4cmd ls` it gives the above error.

So is S4cmd not compatible with other object storage services currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is S4cmd not compatible with other object storage services
>   currently?

The answer seems to be yes: [S4cmd](https://github.com/bloomreach/s4cmd) is not compatible with other object storage services.

While the names of the tools are similar, [S3cmd](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd) is a project written by Michal Ludvig and [S4cmd](https://github.com/bloomreach/s4cmd) is written by Chou-han Yang for BloomReach. And as stated under [“Unimplemented features”](https://github.com/bloomreach/s4cmd#unimplemented-features) in the official code repository for [S4cmd](https://github.com/bloomreach/s4cmd):

> #### Unimplemented features
>
> - CloudFront or other feature support beyond basic S3 access.

So it seems that (currently) [S4cmd] is strictly a tool designed for Amazon S3 object storage.

In contrast, under the [“What is S3cmd”](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd#what-is-s3cmd) heading for that project’s official repository it states; bold emphasis is mine:

> S3cmd (`s3cmd`) is a free command line tool and client for uploading, retrieving and **managing data in Amazon S3 and other cloud storage service providers that use the S3 protocol, such as Google Cloud Storage or DreamHost DreamObjects**.

Answer (score 0):

According to s4cmd's [issue tracker](https://github.com/bloomreach/s4cmd/issues/107#issuecomment-389985603), they [merged a PR](https://github.com/bloomreach/s4cmd/pull/82) in 2018 which lets you set up Wasabi or other s3-compatible object storage endpoints. However, you need to [install from source](https://github.com/bloomreach/s4cmd/issues/107#issuecomment-400542901) and [YMMV](https://github.com/bloomreach/s4cmd/issues/93#issuecomment-391396202).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `s4cmd --endpoint-url=YOUR_ENDPOINT_URL ...`